# Extract part of a path in batch

Tags: batch-file

What's the simplest way in batch to get part of a path?

From other 'suggested questions' I'm now aware of `~dp0`, but it seems like that only works on the current working directory?

I want to get a substring out of an environment variable, instead. Specifically, everything up to the final `\`.

In bash, I can do this with `newpath=${fullpath%\\*}`, is there an equivalently simple batch construct?

Comment: you need one or more for loops to get parent folders from `%~dp0`

Comment: Am I mistaken in my understanding that `~dp0` gives output based on the current directory, then? Could you give a brief example of using it with a path stored as a variable?

Comment: ~dp0 returns the drive:path of the command line - so if you typed `c:\bat\test.bat` and the current directory was `d:\backups` then ~dp0 would return `c:\bat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From how I read your question, you want the parent directory for the specified path.

Building on what RGuggisberg answered you can do something like this.

```
@echo off
call :Parent "%~dp0"
exit /b 0

:Parent <Path>
pushd "%~f1\.." || exit /b 1
echo %CD%
popd
exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to eliminate a trailing backslash from an environment variable:

```
@echo off
set "var=c:\program files\rock & roll\"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%var%\.") do echo set "var=%%~fa"
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I actually wanted to remove `rock & roll` in this instance, not a trailing backslash, though looking at my Q again perhaps that wasn't clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way to do it (assuming variable fullpath contains path).  This works whether there is a trailing \ or not.  Another way is to trim the last character, but that assumes you always have a trailing \, which you may not???  Of course you may want to store %cd% in some other variable instead of echoing it.

```
pushd %fullpath%
echo.%cd%
popd
```

Comment: @jam See the output of `help set`.

Comment: jam,  %cd% is the current directory.  You can find that on one of the multiple HELP pages for  SET /?  as suggested by Ansgar Wiechers.

Comment: @RGuggisberg, I tried your suggestion and it's giving me the full path (the final part of %fullpath% is a folder, not a filename, if that makes a difference?)